# How to use a where query inside a laravel relationship?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

Hello i have a CommentRetours table which connects the retours to the comments.

The DB:

[image]

I need to display all comments for a user and return that to the view.

I now have this query:

```
    $comments = CommentRetours::with(['comments' => function($q) {
        $q->where('user_id',Auth()->user()->id);
    }])->get();
```

This return NULL..

The user_id is inside the comments table.

As constructure example i will add this:

[image]

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Check output of `Auth()->user()->id`. I think it should be as `auth()->user()->id`.

Comment: @iCode i checked it with dd(); it returns correct output

Comment: Can you show your `comments` relation?

Comment: Hello @iCode i fixed the problem will post answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by adding `user_id` to the `CommentRetours` table, now I wont have to query inside the other relationship.

I can just see `user_id` directly inside the table.

Answer (score 2):

The question is quite old but the solution adopted by OP being less than ideal, here is what he probably should have done:

```
$comments = CommentRetours::whereHas(['comments' => function($q) {
    $q->where('user_id', Auth::id());
}])->with('comments')->get();
```

`whereHas` checks if the `CommentRetours` have some comments that match the condition.

I also replaced `Auth()->user()->id` by `Auth::id()`.